# Корректно ли в контроллере иметь методы кроме API?

Tags: java, mvc, controller

Коллеги, корректно ли по методологии, в контроллере ли иметь служебные методы по типу findEmployeeOrElseThrow, как в примере?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findById(@RequestParam int id)  {
        return findEmployeeOrElseThrow(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> delete(@RequestParam int id) {
        findEmployeeOrElseThrow(id);
        employeeService.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    private Employee findEmployeeOrElseThrow(int id) {
        return employeeService.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Не найден сотрудник по id = " + id));
    }
```

}

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Чему это противоречит?

Comment: На самом деле оно может противоречит лишь правилам принятым на проекте (экзотики бывают разными). Если они позволяют такое то с флагом в руки и в перёд

Comment: @AzizUmarov Насколько я понимаю, назначение контроллера - это только связующее звено между клиентом и системой, а остальное стоит помещать, например в сервис. Буду благодарен если посоветуете материалы на эту тему.

Comment: Назначение да. Но иметь приватные методы в контроллере никто не запрещает. Тем более чтобы понизить цикломатическую сложность чато прибегают к такому методу

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да, вообще я поместил этот метод в сервис, но столкнулся со сложностью замокать этот метод в модульном тесте контроллера. Т.к. в таком моке приходится писать всю логику метода.

Comment: это приватный метод и зачем его мокать не пойму

Comment: @AzizUmarov Мокать если метод находится в сервисе, при тестировании контроллера

Comment: Вы мокаете публичный на чтобы вернул нужный результат в зависимости от состояния

Comment: пускаете один Id мокаете exeption и другой тест мокаете с результатом без ексепшона

Comment: это противоречит одноименному паттерну GRASP , который так и именуется "контроллер". суть его состоит в том, чтобы инкапсулировать систему он внешних воздействий. отсюда родилась мысль о том, что контроллер должен быть максимально "тонкий". и именно отсюда следует, что тыкать логику в контроллер - плохая идея. а в данном конкретном приведенном примере проблема вообще не в историях про контроллер. если вы так сделаете в сервисе, это тоже будет плохо. Задача: вызвать 1 метод у employeeService. Решение простое: вызвать этот метод. А в данном решении мы создаем метод, чтобы вызвать этот метод.

Comment: с тем же успехом можно создать еще 10 приватных методов, делигирующих вызов друг другу. посему ответ простой: писать логику в контроллере - зло, делать "удаленные вызовы" - зло. убираем лишний метод и вызываем сервис прям из метода контроллера findById

Comment: @Дмитрий Я создал метод findEmployeeOrElseThrow чтобы исключить дублирование кода. У меня эта логика выполнялась три раза в контроллере, наверное стоило это полнее показать. Сейчас я отредактировал пример - добавил метод delete.

Comment: этот метод должен быть в сервисе, а не в контроллере. ну то есть в сервисе помимо стандартного findById нужен еще findByIdOrElseThrow на уровне сервис леера. а в идеале на уровне абстрактного класса, написанного с помощью дженериков, от которого наследуются все сервисы, дабы не копировать 1000 раз логику получения по айди и остальную

Comment: тоже самое ,кстати, касается удаления. возможно целесообразно на уровне сервисов изначально проверять наличие объекта по айди. с высокой вероятностью это правило касается всего вашего сервиса, иначе это странно. сервис же не для того, чтобы просто делигировать вызов репозиторию))

Comment: @Дмитрий Вообще, в моём  учебном примере, сервисы да, по большей части только делигируют вызовы в репозиторий. Вы имеете ввиду, что нужно в каждом методе сервиса, который предполагает наличие объекта в БД сделать проверку и выброс исключения? Т.е. чтобы контроллер по большей части, вообще не знал об этой проверке?

Comment: не в каждом методе сервиса. к примеру из вашего контроллера следует, что при удалении вы сначала хотите проверить наличие сущности и бросить исключение, если ее нет. это касается сущности Employee, потому что контроллер отвечает за работу с Employee. но это же мега странно, если при попытке удаления другой сущности в случае, если ее не окажется, вернется ок??!!

Comment: логично, если удаление любой несуществующей сущности вашего сервиса приведет к исключению. это значит , что на уровне сервисов в методе удаления должна быть добавлена такая проверка и выброс исключения.

Comment: а еще логичнее иметь один абстрактный сервис, который основан на дженериках, принимает в конструктор спринговый репозиторий (тоже на дженериках). теперь вы можете все стандартные крудовские методы плюс доп логику к ней (типа предварительной проверки с выбросом исключения перед удалением) описать на уровне этого абстрактного класса. а потом все сервисы просто наследуете от этого абстрактного сервиса и получаете от него все написанные в нем методы и не переписываете от сервиса к сервису получение по айди или удаление с выбросом исключения при отсутствии сущности

Comment: а уж если у вас совсем больное воображение и вы не всегда хотите одинаково выполнять логику удаления, то тогда переопределение в помощь, но это бред